# Dropping nonsingular term in OPE

Tags: conformal-field-theory

Why (in 2D CFT; I don't know if this statement can be generalized to other theories), for the purpose of calculating the correlation functions, non-singular term in the OPE is always dropped?

Comment: Well, if you are ever in a situation where you could not shrink the two operators close to each other such that the non-singular terms become close to zero, you should of course keep them. That just almost never happens, I think.

Comment: I don't really see why we shrink 2 operators in the first place, and one of the reason is that if you have many point insertions, then you don't have that freedom after fixing the position of certain vertices. Besides, there's always a possibility of a constant term comes out of the OPE.

Could you please explain it in a little bit more details?

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I don't want to make this an answer (and I'm not 100% certain this is correct), but, for example, look at the way you get the commutation relations for modes of two fields from the OPE - you use a Cauchy integral, which vanishes if the integrand is non-singular inside, and if you know the commutation of all modes of all fields, the theory is completely fixed, so the regular terms contain no information.

Comment: It's because calculating OPEs in CFTs involves contour integrations. This is usually described in the first few chapters of any CFT book. The non-singular (holomorphic) terms then give a non-zero contribution but the non-singular (and specifically 1/x terms) contribute. Higher terms like ($1/x^2$) and ($1/x^3$),etc from one term in the OPE can be multiplied from non-singular terms like $x$ and $x^2$ from another term and contribute as well. Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/159443/question-about-correlation-functions-of-2d-cfts/159622#159622

Comment: Thank you, @Heterotic; however, let's consider the following examples:
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168214/correlation-functions-on-s2-from-ope-singularities